# Calling MM42, dirty assign of variables in SAPLCTMS for atnam and atwrts - Any experience?

Tags: abap, sap-erp

In a custom program I call the retail material transaction (change, so MM42).

The user could change attribute values ( meaning ATWRT ) which are placed on the screen.

The debugger tells me, that there are a lot of variables, some seem to  be the right ones, IF ONLY ONE atwrt of an atnam is changed. In case of multiple atwrt changes on more than one atnam, my dirty assign would only know the LAST ATNAM and it's new ATWRT.

This question adresses those developers, which might have already done this and may give me a hint, which one of the dozens of tables could track all the atnams and atwrts and also being possible to assign it in my calling program,after the MM42 returns.

IS there anybody in here, who may have done this, so I could save a bit of (maybe even lost) time ?

Comment: I don’t think you’ve provided enough information? What are you actually trying to accomplish?  What is the actual code you’ve written, where?

Comment: I can provide some code, where You will see a call transaction and an remmed attempt to assign  the proper variable from the mentioned program in order to get all actual atwrts of the program.

Comment: Why do you need this? And give the code

Comment: Why? Man... I want to avoid another select and act similar to m of mvc. Code will follow.

Comment: My bounty expires soon... anyone interested ?